# Calculating values in PHP with buttons

Tags: php, forms, button

I am creating a calculator in PHP and I should have this kind of structure of my HTML, where my numbers are clickable buttons, and the number that has been first clicked will be the first value and the second number I click will be the second value.  I have no idea on how its gonna work, is it possible? if so how here's my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id = "structure">
            <?php
                if(isset($_GET)){
                    $value += $_GET;
                }
            ?>
                <form method = "GET " action = "calculator.php">
                    <input type = "submit" name = "one" value = 1>
                    <input type = "submit" name = "two" value = 2>
                    <input type = "submit" name = "three" value = 3>
                    <input type = "submit" name = "operand" value = "+">
                    </br>
                    <input type = "submit" name = "four" value = 4>
                    <input type = "submit" name = "five" value = 5>
                    <input type = "submit" name = "six" value = 6>
                    <input type = "submit" name = "operand" value = "-">
                    </br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I haven't put all the numbers in the calculator for posting purposes

Comment: Why not use JavaScript instead? It would logically be easier.

Comment: it is an exercise in my book and I feel the urge I have to do it, but the book doesn't give any idea on how to do it. but I do not have any idea how.

Comment: what do you get when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the best way to do this is to use Client-side coding (Javascript). However, if you have to write a PHP code, then you need to submit the form twice. The first time, put the input variable (first number) in a hidden input element of the form and have print the html again this time with the extra hidden input element. The second time, look for that hidden input value: if it exists then it means that the new input is the second number and the hidden input is the first number. Get the value of the hidden input, get the new number, add them together and display the results. Make sure you reset the hidden input value.

Comment: You will need three submits for basic math. Number (submit) operand (submit) number (submit). This grows as you add multi-digit numbers.

Comment: True. My impression was that he would only work with single digit numbers based on the description of the problem. You are right about the operand though.

Comment: I'm probably being way to detailed by accommodating for multi-digit numbers in a simple (or what was meant to be simple) book exercise, so agreed on that.

Comment: its no longer a book exercise. I decided it should be a personal exercise where it can accomodate multi digit numbers. so can anyone post how? I really have no idea how to work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a book exercise and the point is for you to write the code, I'm not going to give you any code. But, I can point you in the right direction (or at least one of them).

Consider using some kind of value that can be sent with each request that stores the current accumulated value of all operations. This probably should be displayed somewhere and also placed in a field that PHP will be able to read on form submit (Hint: have you ever heard of the hidden input type?). How will you keep track of the last operation? Maybe you could use another one of these fields to store the operation until another button is pushed.

What code can you use to check if the form is submitted? How can you check which button is pushed. Which values will be set if `+` is pushed? How about if a number is pushed? What if multiple numbers are pushed in a row?

More things to consider: Try playing with a real calculator. When are results displayed? What order of operations is used? Every operation has a left hand side and a right hand side. What happens when you push multiple numbers in a row. What about decimals? Should there be a clear button?

Comment: I have no idea what are hidden inputs, can you give an example?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="leftHandSide" value="0" />` They aren't displayed to the user, but they are sent to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: btw my other problem is that each time I click the button, the values are not being stored... only the single values. why is it like that? is it because when a form is click the page reloads? can please put an example code? I really have no idea how is thsi gonna work

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a way to keep track of previous inputs. Every time you click a button, a request gets sent to the server with that info (in `$_GET`) but the old inputs are no longer available. A few methods:

**Hidden form elements**

Each time the user clicks, you read the value and output it back into the page in a hidden form element. Each time you have to read the value of the hidden element using your existing method with `$_GET`, figure out what you need to do mathematically, and save the old stuff and new stuff into the hidden element again for the next input.

See [this page](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlhidden.php) for an example.

**Cookies**

You can use [`setcookie`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to set a cookie with the value the user entered. Each time the user clicks a button, you want to load the value from the cookie and append the current input. When the user clicks the `=` button, you load the cookie data and parse the expression. You make it easier and store the parts of the expression in some kind of delimited string in the cookie so you have `operand,operator,operand` and then you can easily compute the result. Hitting a clear button would clear the value of the cookie.

This [tizag tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpcookies.php) is a pretty good example of what you want to do with cookies.

**Javascript**

Obviously the easiest way. Since the state will be maintained, you don't need to pass values back and forth.